# Bluetooth scanning working but available Bluetooth devices are not found

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am using an Android 9 Pie API level. I am sending an available device using intent to another activity from below code using Broadcast in multiple ways.

Paired device list show perfectly but available nearby device not found when the search finishes. But don't know why it is not working.

```
private ActivityMainBinding binding;
private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mDeviceList = new ArrayList<>();
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDlg;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    mProgressDlg = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mProgressDlg.setMessage("Scanning Device");
    mProgressDlg.setCancelable(false);
    mProgressDlg.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();

            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
    });

    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        showUnsupported();
    } else {
        binding.btnViewPaired.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

                if (pairedDevices == null || pairedDevices.size() == 0) {
                    showToast("No Paired Devices Found");
                } else {
                    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> list = new ArrayList<>();

                    list.addAll(pairedDevices);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DeviceListActivity.class);

                    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("device.list", list);

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

        binding.btnScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            }
        });

        binding.btnEnable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    mBluetoothAdapter.disable();

                    showDisabled();
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);

                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1000);
                }
            }
        });

        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            showEnabled();
        } else {
            showDisabled();
        }
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
    }

    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);

    super.onDestroy();
}

private void showEnabled() {
    binding.tvStatus.setText("Bluetooth is On");
    binding.tvStatus.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    binding.btnEnable.setText("Disable");
    binding.btnEnable.setEnabled(true);
    binding.btnViewPaired.setEnabled(true);
    binding.btnScan.setEnabled(true);
}

private void showDisabled() {
    binding.tvStatus.setText("Bluetooth is Off");
    binding.tvStatus.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    binding.btnEnable.setText("Enable");
    binding.btnEnable.setEnabled(true);
    binding.btnViewPaired.setEnabled(false);
    binding.btnScan.setEnabled(false);
}

private void showUnsupported() {
    binding.tvStatus.setText("Bluetooth is unsupported by this device");
    binding.btnEnable.setText("Enable");
    binding.btnEnable.setEnabled(false);
    binding.btnViewPaired.setEnabled(false);
    binding.btnScan.setEnabled(false);
}

private void showToast(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

///// Boradcast recever to handle
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
            final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

            if (state == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON) {
                showToast("Bluetooth Enabled");

                showEnabled();
            }
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
            mDeviceList = new ArrayList<>();

            mProgressDlg.show();
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            mProgressDlg.dismiss();

            Intent newIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DeviceListActivity.class);

            newIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("device.list", mDeviceList);

            startActivity(newIntent);
        } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            mDeviceList.add(device);

            showToast("Found device " + device.getName());
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't think it's helping if you repeatedly tell people to help you urgently.

Comment: I have edited this question again. Please do not add a quote block again - your own words are not a quote. Please do not add begging messages again - that will just be edited out again, and attract downvotes.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.